# Let $S=\{q \in \Bbb Q :0<q<1\}$. We can define a number $b \in (0,1)$ that is not in the list of elements of S. Is $b$ rational?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $S=\{q \in \Bbb Q :0\lt q \lt 1\}$.  We know $S$ is countable, and thus can enumerate its elements: $q_1, q_2, q_3,\dots$  Since each of these rational numbers has an infinite decimal expansion $q_i=0.q_{i1}q_{i2}q_{i3}\dots$, one can define a real number $b \in (0,1)$ that is not in the list as in Cantor's diagonal argument.  Is $b$ a rational number?

My immediate thought is just no, as it is not in the list of all possible rational numbers in $(0,1)$, but I've nothing but intuition here.

Comment: The correct question, I think, is whether $b$ _could be_ a rational number, and if so, what number it could then be and what arrangement of elements of $S$ allows this. To reduce the number of choices, you can consider binary expansions instead, then $b$ is uniquely determined by the Cantor’s construction from the sequence of elements of $S$.

Comment: And the answer would be no, that it couldn't possibly be a rational number, correct?  If we're considering the decimal expansions for a rational number, rearranging its digits either converts it to another rational number already in the list, or it becomes irrational.  I suppose if it could be rational, then we could say the same for any such real number on $(0,1)$, and thus the reals would be countable.

Comment: Just be sure that $b$ doesn't have a tail of all 9's or all 0's in order to be sure it has a unique decimal representation (which is easy to do by choosing digits other than 0 and 9 when constructing $b$). Then $b$ won't be equal to any number on the list, and hence must be irrational.

Comment: Ah, I understand that caveat now.  Thanks much!

Comment: @GeorgeWKush The answer is no because if $b$ is rational, then it occurs somewhere on the list, say as the $n$th element. But $b$ differs in at least the $n$th position from the $n$th element, i.e. from itself, which is impossible.

Comment: Since *by definition*, $S$ contains *all* rational numbers between $0$ and $1$, anything that doesn't belong to $S$ but is a number in the interval $(0,1)$ cannot be rational. Cantor's diagonal argument has nothing to do with this, except because you're using it for defining such a number. Every method that defines a number in $(0,1)$ that doesn't belong to $S$ will define a nonrational number.

Comment: Here is a related question: given $b\in S$, can you always arrange the elements in $S\setminus\{b\}$ so that the algorithm in Cantor’s argument yields $b$ (say, for binary expansions)?